# image recognition using hybrid cnn+svm model

Tags: python-3.x

To recognize the image I am using cnn+svm hybrid model.
model:

```
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense((classes), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))

    model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

compiling model:

```
    opt = Adam(lr=lr, decay=lr / epochs)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_hinge", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Is this correct? When the training process, the accuracy not improving ....
what is the wrong with this code...

Comment: Could you share the error message that you are seeing, or the output (expected and actual)?

Comment: Epoch 1/20
322/322 [==============================] - 76s 237ms/step - loss: 1.1993 - acc: 0.0423 - val_loss: 1.0022 - val_acc: 0.0453
Epoch 2/20
322/322 [==============================] - 81s 253ms/step - loss: 1.0018 - acc: 0.0372 - val_loss: 1.0018 - val_acc: 0.0369
Epoch 3/20
322/322 [==============================] - 84s 261ms/step - loss: 1.0014 - acc: 0.0396 - val_loss: 1.0011 - val_acc: 0.0447

Comment: I am getting low level accuracy only.  what is the wrong with this code?